# CSOM - Trying to access "Client_Title" from a page in a list - "The property/Field has not been initialized ..... "

Tags: sharepoint-online, development, csom, remote-event-receiver, .net

I'm trying to access the "Client_Title/Page Title" from a page in Site Pages using **Client Context** and **"listItemId"**. It seems that I'm not requesting or loading it the correct way.

When debugging I see that ListItemId is the valid Id of the item.

I *appreciate every help I can get.*

[image: Problem pic]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've reworked your code to resolve the issue

- store the GetById in a variable before sending out the query
- make sure you include client title in the query of the item
- it seems you are composing many queries that you end up not using since you know the id of the item you want

e.g.

```
var changedItem2 = listitem.GetById(listitemId);            
context.Load(changedItem2, item => item.Client_Title);
context.ExecuteQuery();

var title2 = changedItem2.Client_Title;
```

**EDIT:**

an even better approach would be to do a single query line and get rid of everything else

```
var changedItem2 = context.Web.Lists.GetByTitle("Site Pages").GetItemById(listitemId);
context.Load(changedItem2, item => item.Client_Title);
context.ExecuteQuery();
```